# Hash password parameter - .NET 8 Identity API

Tags: c#, hash, asp.net-core-identity, .net-8.0

I've implemented the .NET 8 Identity API, so I got the `/login` and `/register` endpoints.

The problem is that both endpoints expect a string password parameter, but I want these endpoints receiving an hashed password.

Using Swagger I have to type the plain password, I would like to send a hashed password.

[image: String password screenshot]

This is my `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Repository")));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication();

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<User>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Scheme = "bearer",
        BearerFormat = "BearerToken",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Description = "Bearer Token Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http
    });

    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = "bearer",
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.MapGroup("/api/Identity").MapIdentityApi<User>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

I've searched about `PasswordHasher` and `DataProtector`, but they were both dead ends.

Comment: If you send a hashed password then the hashed password is the password it does not matter you called it hashed as an attacker just needs that hash to authenticate against your api.

Comment: @Ralf it makes sense, what is the correct approach to solve this, use a SSL connection is the way?

Comment: You should always use encrypted transport yes.